# Converse of closed graph theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, banach-spaces, closed-graph

Suppose $Y$ is a normed linear space. If for every Banach space $X$ and for every linear operator $T:X\to Y$, graph of $T$ is closed implies $T$ is continuous, then can we prove that $Y$ is a Banach space?

Comment: Perhaps this helps https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434515/converse-of-closed-graph-theorem/434520#434520

Comment: @Anupam: your question was answered in Math Overflow a week ago. Why are you asking it again here?

Comment: @Martin Argerami: The questions are not same. The answer of mathoverflow says that every closed operator from a baralled space to a Banach space is continuous. Now I want to know about the codomain.

Comment: Fair enough, my bad.